# Filter dataframe: extract rows with only one column that meets condition

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to filter a data frame that looks like the one below. I want to extract the genes for which **only one** day in the range of Day05 to Day28 of that gene has a value of less than 0.01. I tried using filter_at(), but I can only filter according to any_vars() or all_vars(). If anyone could help, it would be much appreciated.

```
    Gene      Day02        Day05        Day07         Day10        Day14        Day21        Day28        Day42
    a          1.523292e-05 7.393226e-03 4.854668e-10  2.810098e-01 5.136247e-02 3.933508e-01 6.911352e-03 6.667379e-03
    Adh        4.942919e-13 7.805973e-02 2.085311e-02  1.077458e-06 1.893881e-06 8.745486e-01 9.475482e-01 7.175556e-10
    bib        3.278391e-05 8.039599e-01 6.316572e-01  3.237931e-04 7.962826e-06 2.714483e-01 9.493604e-01 6.805985e-03
```

Comment: The Stack tag-recommendation engine is imperfect, please be mindful of the tags you use. In this case, [tag:rstudio] is not correct because this has nothing to do with the IDE itself (just the programming language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero rows in your data reflect that condition:

```r
subset(dat, select = Day05:Day28) <= 0.01
#   Day05 Day07 Day10 Day14 Day21 Day28
# 1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# 2 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# 3 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

rowSums(subset(dat, select = Day05:Day28) < 0.01)
# 1 2 3 
# 3 2 2
```

meaning that there are three such values on row 1, and two values on rows 2 and 3.

However, I'll use `0.005` instead, and we find something.

### base R

```r
lim <- 0.005
dat[rowSums(subset(dat, select = Day05:Day28) < lim) == 1, ]
#   Gene        Day02       Day05        Day07     Day10      Day14     Day21       Day28       Day42
# 1    a 1.523292e-05 0.007393226 4.854668e-10 0.2810098 0.05136247 0.3933508 0.006911352 0.006667379
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  filter(., rowSums(select(., Day05:Day28) < lim) == 1)
#   Gene        Day02       Day05        Day07     Day10      Day14     Day21       Day28       Day42
# 1    a 1.523292e-05 0.007393226 4.854668e-10 0.2810098 0.05136247 0.3933508 0.006911352 0.006667379
```